# Jenkins run all groups instead of specified group as goal

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

I am doing automation using Selenium webdriver, Maven, TestNG and jenkins.

**TestNG code:**

```
@Test(groups="Support")
public void method1()
{
   //Logic here  

}

@Test(groups="Login")
public void method2()
{
   //Logic here  

}
```

In Jenkins I have specified Goal:

```
test -Dgroup=Support
```

But issue is when I run through jenkins , It runs both group methods. Login group and Support group.

Comment: Can you please post your stack trace which you have given in Jenkins UI?

Comment: shouldn't it be test -Dgroups=Support ? Notice "s" at the end

Comment: @chrisl08 - thanks. It works.:)

Comment: thank you for marking the answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't it be test -Dgroups=Support ? Notice "s" at the end